# Comparing between two skeleton tracking on processing 3

Tags: java, image-processing, processing, skeleton-code

I am currently doing my dissertation which would involve in having 2 people a professional athlete and an amateur. First with the image processing skeletonization I would like to record the professional athlete while performing the squat exercise , then when the amateur performs the exercise I want to be able to compare the professional skeleton with that of the amateur to see if it is properly formed.

Please I m open for any suggestions and opinions , Would gladly appreciate some help

Comment: Please turn to the  [help] and take the tour; to understand what/how to ask here. So you understand that your question is **way** too broad. We help with specific questions on programming; not with me "me vision, but no idea; please fill that gap" kind of input.

Comment: why don't you present a few example images with annotations. so far i have no idea if you are talking about x-ray images, photos, 3d datasets...
provide more info and especially a specific problem/question. why skeletonization? do you have any image-processing background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here lies your question:

> properly formed.

What does properly performed actually mean ? How can this be quantified ?

Bare in mind I'm not an athletic/experienced in this field.
If I were given the task I would counter-intuitively go in the opposite direction:
moving away form Processing 3/kinect/computer. I would instead:

1. find a professional athlete
2. find a skilled with trainer with functional mobility training.
3. find an amateur (probably easiest)

Item 2 will be trickier.For example [FMS](http://www.functionalmovement.com/) seems to put a lot of emphasis on **correct** exercising and mobility (to enhance performance and reduce risk of injuries). I'm not sure if that's the only approach or the best. You might want to check opinions on [Physical Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/), consult with people studying/teaching exercise science, etc. Do check credentials as it feels like a field where everyone has an opinion/preference.

The idea is to understand how a professional educated trainer asses correct movement. Take note of how that works in the real world and try to systemise it.

What are the cues for a correct execution ?

- is the key poses
- the motion in between
- how the skeletal and muscular system work together/ the weights/forces applied/etc.

Having a better understanding of how this works in the real world should lead you to things you can start quantifying/comparing numerically on a computer.

Try to make a checklist/score system manually using a pen and paper based on the information you gather. If this works you already have a system you can start programming.

The next step is acquiring the data. 
This is probably where the kinect comes, but bare in mind:

- the second version of the kinect is more precise than the first
- there is a [Kinect2 SDK wrapper for Processing 3](http://codigogenerativo.com/kinectpv2/): use that if you can (windows only). There is a way you can get [libfreenect2 working with OpenNI on osx/linux](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/issues/714) and therefore with SimpleOpenNI in Processing, but it's not straight forward and you won't have the same precision on the skeleton tracking algorithm
- use data that is as precise as possible:

  - you can get the accuracy of a tracked skeleton joint
  - use an environment that doesn't contain a complex background (makes it easy to segment users and detect/track skeletons with little change of mistaking it for something else). prefer artificial non-incandescent light (less of a problem with kinect v2, but still you want as little IR interference as possible).
  - comparing orientation matrices or joints on single poses might not be enough to get the full picture: how do you capture/quantify motion taking into account the things that the kinect can't easily see: muscles flexing/forces applied/moving centre of gravity/etc.
  - try to use a grid system that will make it simple to pair the digital values with real world measurements. Check out how people used to study motion in the past, for example [Étienne-Jules Marey](http://hyperallergic.com/197464/the-scientist-who-shot-his-photos-with-a-gun-and-inspired-futurism/) or [Eadweard Muybridge](http://www.eadweardmuybridge.co.uk/muybridge_image_and_context/human_figure_in_motion/)

[image: Marey motion capture]

Motion capture by Étienne-Jules Marey

[image: Muybridge motion study]

Motion study by Eadweard Muybridge (notice the grid)

It's a pretty full on project to get right involving bits of anatomy/physics/kinematics/etc.

Start with the research first:

- how did people study this in the past ?
- what are the current developments ?
- how does it work in the real world (without computers) ?

Take your constraints into account:

- what resources (people/gear/etc.) can you use ?
- how much time do you have available ?
  Given the above, what topic/section of the project can be realistically be tackled to get useful results.

Overall probably something along these lines:

- background research
- real world studies
- comparison system has feature which can be measured both with kinect and by a person
- record data (real world data + mobility comparison evalutation and kinect data + mobility comparison)
- compare data
- write evaluation of findings (how effective is the system? what are limitations ? what could be improved (future work) ? etc.)

In short be aware of the kinect limitations: skeleton tracking is probability based: it's not 100% accurate. use data that's as clean/correct as possible to begin with (make it easy to acquire good data if you can control the capture environment). From what a real trainer would track, what could you track with a kinect ? do a comparison of the intersecting measurements.

Comment: I`m so sorry I didnt thank you for this and the effort you put to answer me back ! Excuse my rude manners , please do  as I m still new at this and i m trying to figure out how it works ! Once again apologies for my rudeness

Comment: No worries. Feel free to vote/mark the answer if it was helpful ;)
Best of luck with the project ! In terms of how the site works, be sure to check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't done so already and earn yourself a badge :D (it's quite different from forums: more strict, but a LOT more efficient because of it)

Comment: I wish I can but I do not have enough points to vote ! but for an answer like that .... 10+ :D